# Scale inline SVG with DIV wrapper

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to scale an inline SVG without touching the SVG? So that only the wrapper div is able to change the width / height according to the image ratio?

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/sekmwfdg/1/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="flag-icon-css-gb" width="640" height="480">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="a">
        <path fill-opacity=".67" d="M-85.333 0h682.67v512h-682.67z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="translate(80) scale(.94)">
      <g stroke-width="1pt">
        <path fill="#006" d="M-256 0H768.02v512.01H-256z"/>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M-256 0v57.244l909.535 454.768H768.02V454.77L-141.515 0H-256zM768.02 0v57.243L-141.515 512.01H-256v-57.243L653.535 0H768.02z"/>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M170.675 0v512.01h170.67V0h-170.67zM-256 170.67v170.67H768.02V170.67H-256z"/>
        <path fill="#c00" d="M-256 204.804v102.402H768.02V204.804H-256zM204.81 0v512.01h102.4V0h-102.4zM-256 512.01L85.34 341.34h76.324l-341.34 170.67H-256zM-256 0L85.34 170.67H9.016L-256 38.164V0zm606.356 170.67L691.696 0h76.324L426.68 170.67h-76.324zM768.02 512.01L426.68 341.34h76.324L768.02 473.848v38.162z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

It should work for all modern Browsers + IE 11

Comment: Use **viewBox**: this  `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="flag-icon-css-gb" viewBox="0 0 640 480" >` instead of this `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="flag-icon-css-gb" width="640" height="480">` If no width and height declared the svg will take the size of yhe `wrapper `

Answer (score 0):

You should add `viewBox="0 0 640 480"` to you `svg` tag and it will take width and height from its parent container

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="flag-icon-css-gb"  viewBox="0 0 640 480">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="a">
        <path fill-opacity=".67" d="M-85.333 0h682.67v512h-682.67z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="translate(80) scale(.94)">
      <g stroke-width="1pt">
        <path fill="#006" d="M-256 0H768.02v512.01H-256z"/>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M-256 0v57.244l909.535 454.768H768.02V454.77L-141.515 0H-256zM768.02 0v57.243L-141.515 512.01H-256v-57.243L653.535 0H768.02z"/>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M170.675 0v512.01h170.67V0h-170.67zM-256 170.67v170.67H768.02V170.67H-256z"/>
        <path fill="#c00" d="M-256 204.804v102.402H768.02V204.804H-256zM204.81 0v512.01h102.4V0h-102.4zM-256 512.01L85.34 341.34h76.324l-341.34 170.67H-256zM-256 0L85.34 170.67H9.016L-256 38.164V0zm606.356 170.67L691.696 0h76.324L426.68 170.67h-76.324zM768.02 512.01L426.68 341.34h76.324L768.02 473.848v38.162z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```